# Converting map.js in Rails routes.rb to new Rails 3 DSL

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dsl, routes

I am try to convert an older DSL style routes.rb file in a project I am working on to the new DSL style used in Rails 3. Since most of it consists of regular routes, the conversion seems simple. Most of it just goes like:

```
RailsRoot::Application.routes.draw do |map|
  root :to => "index#index"
  match '/table/create' => "table#create"
  match '/table/delete' => "table#delete"

  # A bunch more of similar match statements

  map.js ':controller/:action.:format'
end
```

I've been following the documentation at [engine yard](http://blog.engineyard.com/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3) to do the conversion. If I am reading it right, it looks like to me I should be able to just remove the surrounding `draw do |map|` code and since under the new DSL, the `:to` tag seems to be assumed unless stated otherwise, the match statements should be able to be left as is and work. (However, I could be entirely wrong in my assumption and possibly have that be my main problem.)

The issue I think I am having is when I get down to that line that says `map.js ':controller/:action.:format'`, I have no clue how to convert that for the Rails 3 style DSL for routing. How would I go about converting this?

#### Edit #1:

I just ran rake routes after converting it with Iuri G's comment suggestion, and it's actually complaining about `root` not being defined. So Iuri G probably gave me the correct solution, but I need to solve this other problem first before I can verify it.

#### Edit #2:

I am an idiot for not realizing this. Since all the example code I saw excluded this part, I thought I didn't need it anymore. However, what I was missing was this line:
`RailsRoot::Application.routes.draw do`
and then having the rest of the routes inside the block. I feel really silly right now. Anyways, Iuri G was right on the money. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'`

Comment: Huh, maybe I should have just asked about the conversion in general rather than that one specific line. I tried your suggestion along with what else I said I did for the conversion and it still breaks. If I swap it out for the old version, it works fine other than getting that deprecation warning, but I am trying to port this to Rails 3.2 so I need to use the new style.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the changes I made. Either way, you were right. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As luri G. stated earlier, the correct way to convert it is by changing it to:

`match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'`